# Cannot obtain a valid XeTeX MiKTeX distribution: from where can I obtain it

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9, miktex-update

From where can I obtain a **valid** MiKTeX distribution.

From official miktex.org I got only the following thing

```
miktex-xetex.exe
```

instead of

```
xetex.exe
```

itself.

And also `miktex-latex.exe` instead of `latex.exe`

```
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   337408 Dec  6 14:09 miktex-t1rawafm.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   373248 Dec  6 14:09 miktex-t1reencode.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   352768 Dec  6 14:09 miktex-t1testpage.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   102400 Dec  6 14:23 miktex-t4ht.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   174592 Dec  6 13:53 miktex-tangle.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   634880 Dec  6 14:28 miktex-tex.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None    48640 Dec  6 13:51 miktex-tex2aspc.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   179200 Dec  6 14:23 miktex-tex4ht.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None  7680000 Dec  6 14:41 miktex-texworks.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   184832 Dec  6 14:27 miktex-tftopl.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   109056 Dec  6 14:20 miktex-ttf2afm.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   159744 Dec  6 14:29 miktex-ttf2pk.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   183808 Dec  6 14:29 miktex-ttf2tfm.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   402432 Dec  6 14:09 miktex-ttftotype42.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   325632 Dec  6 14:26 miktex-upbibtex.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   213504 Dec  6 14:26 miktex-updvitype.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   227840 Dec  6 14:29 miktex-upmendex.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   210432 Dec  6 14:26 miktex-uppltotf.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   744448 Dec  6 14:26 miktex-uptex.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   206336 Dec  6 14:27 miktex-uptftopl.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   211968 Dec  6 14:28 miktex-vftovp.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   200704 Dec  6 14:28 miktex-vptovf.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   205312 Dec  6 14:28 miktex-weave.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None  1269248 Dec  6 14:30 miktex-xetex.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   209408 Dec  6 14:30 miktex-xml2pmx.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   356864 Sep 23  2010 miktex-zip.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   275456 Dec  6 14:15 miktex.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   242688 Dec  6 14:15 miktexsetup.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   328704 Dec  6 14:15 mkfntmap.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   324096 Dec  6 14:16 mpm.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   567688 Dec  2 12:32 msvcp140.dll
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None    23952 Dec  2 12:32 msvcp140_1.dll
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   185744 Dec  2 12:32 msvcp140_2.dll
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None    56200 Dec  2 12:32 msvcp140_atomic_wait.dll
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None    20368 Dec  2 12:32 msvcp140_codecvt_ids.dll
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   178688 Dec  6 14:16 mthelp.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   201728 Dec  6 14:50 mtprint.exe
drwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None        0 Dec 19 01:21 platforms
drwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None        0 Dec 19 01:21 styles
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   272384 Dec  6 14:22 tdsutil.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   286208 Dec  6 14:23 texify.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None  1122768 Sep 11 21:05 ucrtbase.dll
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None   335240 Dec  2 12:32 vccorlib140.dll
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None    97168 Dec  2 12:32 vcruntime140.dll
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None    37264 Dec  2 12:32 vcruntime140_1.dll
-rwxrwx---+ 1 hynek0 None  1589248 Dec  6 14:49 yap.exe
```

```
hynek0@hynek /cygdrive/c/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64
$ ./miktex-xetex.exe a.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (MiKTeX 21.12) (preloaded format=xetex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(a.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  {article}
?

hynek0@hynek /cygdrive/c/MiKTeX7/miktex/bin/x64
$ ./miktex-tex.exe a.tex
This is mikTeX, Version 3.141592653 (MiKTeX 21.12) (preloaded format=tex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(a.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  {article}
?
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \begin
          {document}
?
[1] )
Output written on a.dvi (1 page, 264 bytes).
Transcript written on a.log.
miktex-tex: major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates.

hynek0@hynek /cygdrive/c/MiKTeX7/miktex/bin/x64
```

Comment: These applications are prefixed with `MiKTeX-` because the source code was compiled for this distribution, as far as I know. I use it daily and have no problem.

Comment: this is a  duplicate of your last question the error is that you are uson plain text not latex. it is not a problem with your miktex installation

Comment: Why do you use MiKTeX in cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows box, the automatic install procedure creates symlinks to enable the call of xe(la)tex or pdf(la)tex without the 'miktex' prefix. For Linux I don't know.

Anyway  your problem is not related with these prefixed names.

The command as you call them load by default the plain TeX format (preloaded format=xetex.fmt)
Use instead
`miktex-xelatex <filename>`
or
`miktex-xetex &xelatex <filename>`
to make available the LaTeX macros.